# image url in CSS

Tags: html, css

I was just trying to change my site around a little, but I bumped into a problem which has never happened me before. I want to be able to test the site offline, so this problem is really annoying.

How come when i try to do this:

```
#logo{
    width:145px;
    height:41px;
    background:url('http://biscuithead.ie/images/logo.png') center no-repeat;                           
    display:block;
    float:left;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

it works, but If I change the background line to:

```
background:url('/images/logo.png') center no-repeat;
```

or

```
background:url('images/logo.png') center no-repeat;
```

or

```
background:url(images/logo.png) center no-repeat;
```

or

```
background:url(/images/logo.png) center no-repeat;
```

it dosent work?

The image only seems to display through css when it is actually on the server

I am using DreamWeaver CS5.

Can anyone help we with this weird problem?

Comment: View page on localhost, see source code, post some info about your img src here. Its the correct path?

Comment: Where are the images in relation to your CSS? Is the CSS in a separate file?

Comment: If you could post a demonstration of this problem on your own server this would help us to see what's going wrong; it sounds like it's a file-paths problem, though.

Comment: The images are located in 'index_files'

Comment: but where are the css files in relation? have you tried `../images/logo.png`?

Comment: but the paths to the images in the CSS don't mention `index_files`, is your webserver aliasing `index_files` to `images` ?

Comment: the image is located in index_files, the same location as my css file

Comment: but you see the problem - the urls in the CSS are looking in a folder called `images`, not `index_files`, so is `index_files` aliased by the web-server so you can call it `/images` ?

Comment: Thanks for that, pavium, I hadnt thaught about doing it like that but for some reason it works. Add that as a different answer if you can so I can solve this thing

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Be sure that the image file exists in your computer, and at the correct location.

Without the leading slash: `images/logo.png` is a path relative to the css file. If the css file is at `/sites/example.com/css/styles.css`, the image file must be at `/sites/example.com/css/images/logo.png` (inside the "css" folder)

With the leading slash: `/images/logo.png` is relative to the root folder of the site. If the css file is at `/sites/example.com/css/styles.css`, the image file must be at `/sites/example.com/images/logo.png` (inside the website root folder)

Comment: But if the css file and the image are in the same folder, then logo.png by itself (no slashes, no index_files) should do the job? It dosent...

Comment: @Conor: You mean `background:url('logo.png') center no-repeat;` and the `logo.png` image file at the same folder of the css file (or html file, if the css is inside it)... doesn't work? - Which browser are you using? Which operational system? And which HTTP server?

Comment: Yes. Im using safari on mac os. Its a zeus server

Comment: Ah... Dreamweaver, so it is Windows, you're probably using IE (which version?)... you should try to see the web page by browsing to a http://localhost (not file:// and not from inside Dreamweaver)

Comment: Forgot latest comment! So, you're using Safari / Mac / Zeus server - it is a very unknown environment for me.

Comment: Do you have access rules interfering? (equivalent to ".htaccess" in Apache) - also, try browsing the image file directly (http://localhost/something/logo.png)

Comment: Can you manually load just the image in the browser using http?

Comment: I can use file:// and give the image location on my computer, but I just wanted to ba able to do it relative to the css file so that I wont have to change it when I put the site

Comment: @Conor Use the inbuilt Mac OSX Apache server for offline testing. You can enable it in System Preferences under Sharing, its the Web Sharing tick box.

Comment: @Conor: So you *can't* access the image using http on your local server?

Answer (score 1):

A colleague had this problem because he wasn't testing on a local web server, he was loading the pages in the browser using `file://`.

Comment: Yes, giving the direct link works, but that wont do once I put the website live

Comment: @Conor: Yes, I was suggesting that that was your problem. Obviously not.

Answer (score 0):

I have had image problems previously, My solution is to use Mac OSX's inbuilt Apache Server.
It is very simple to enable, go to System Preferences, Sharing and Tick Web Sharing You can then place files/folders in the Sites Folder in your home folder. To Access these files open your web browser and go to localhost/~Username/
There is an article here that goes into more detail about the process
http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Apache/Using-Apache-and-PHP-on-Mac-OS-X/