# AngularJs HTML5 mode not loading images

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I am using AngularJs to create a SPA on top of the ASP MVC framework. I had everything working great until I enabled HTML5 mode to produce nicer URLs. Now images are not being loaded.

It seems like any requests to my /Images folder are not making it to the server. I have used Fidler to check the traffic and can see all the requests for the partials but nothing for the images.

Here is my AngularJs routes

```
$stateProvider.
      state({
          name: 'home',
          url: '/',
          templateUrl: '/app/public/partials/index.html'
      }).
      state({
          name: 'infoprivacy',
          url: '/info/privacy',
          templateUrl: '/app/public/partials/info/privacy.html'
      }).
      state({
          name: 'infocookie',
          url: '/info/cookie',
          templateUrl: '/app/public/partials/info/cookie.html'
      }).
      state({
          name: 'infoterms',
          url: '/info/terms',
          templateUrl: '/app/public/partials/info/terms.html'
      }).
      state({
          name: 'groups',
          url: '/groups',
          templateUrl: '/app/public/partials/groups/index.html'
      }).
      state({
          name: 'groupsview',
          url: '/groups/view/:id',
          templateUrl: '/app/public/partials/groups/view.html'
      }).
      state({
          name: 'jobs',
          url: '/jobs',
          templateUrl: '/app/public/partials/jobs/index.html',
          controllr: 'JobsCtrl'
      }).
      state({
          name: 'jobsview',
          url: '/jobs/view/:id',
          templateUrl: '/app/public/partials/jobs/view.html'
      }).
      state({
          name: 'jobsnotfound',
          url: '/jobs/notfound',
          templateUrl: '/app/public/partials/jobs/notfound.html'
      }).
      state({
          name: 'login',
          url: '/login',
          templateUrl: '/app/public/partials/login.html'
      }).
      state({
          name: 'error',
          url: '/error/:errorRef',
          templateUrl: '/app/public/partials/error.html'
      }).
      state({
          name: 'cvs',
          url: '/cvs',
          templateUrl: '/app/public/partials/cvs/index.html'
      }).
      state({
          name: 'cvsedit',
          url: '/cvs/edit/:id',
          templateUrl: '/app/public/partials/cvs/edit.html'
      }).
      state({
          name: 'cvsedit.withdlg',
          url: '/:dlg',
          templateUrl: '/app/public/partials/cvs/edit.html'
      }).
      state({
          name: 'profile',
          url: '/profile',
          templateUrl: '/app/public/partials/profile/index.html'
      });

  $urlRouterProvider.when('', '/');

  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
```

This is the CSS for the background image that is not loading

```
#menu .item.navProfile {
    background: url(/Images/icon-nav-profile.png) right 20px no-repeat;
}
```

The HTML that includes the menu is loaded using an ng-include

Comment: Maybe this answer helps - http://stackoverflow.com/a/6161057/2104976

Comment: The problem is that the request for the images doesn't seem to be being sent to the server. I'm guessing AngularJs is trying to route it?

Comment: No way. Open the browser console on Chrome and see if it is able to pick the route up in the network tab.. Or see if there are any errors in console (404 perhaps)?

Comment: Looking at the request in the network tab in chrome it just says it's pending and stays pending forever

Comment: your server side code is missing, and the bug should be here (url rewriting)

Comment: @Bixi as mentioned in my question I have used Fiddler to check the web requests being sent to the server and the request for /Images/icon-nav-profile.png is never sent

Comment: Okay sorry, tried without anti-virus ?

Comment: @Bixi yes. Server side issue was my first thought, that's why I checked it with Fiddler. I thought it might be something obvious that I was missing

Answer (score 0):

There is an addin for the chrome developer tools called Batarang this will help in debugging Angular JS issues.