# Image background URL property is not fetching the image?

Tags: html, css

I am using css `background-image` property for setting cover image for `divs`. 
This property is not fetching background image if name has these brackets `()` in a name e.g **image(2).jpg**

I noticed that these brackets `()` and **spaces** in images names are causing problems because we are using **url** function which also has brackets `()` so one solution is to remove these brackets from all images names. But this is tiresome way because we have thousands of images which are stored in database and folders. So renaming all files is not a best solution.

**Can we do something in css to fix this naming issue? or any alternative solution will be better!**

```
<div style="background-image: url(http://example.com/uploads/unnamed%20(41).jpg);">
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [image url in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6161016/image-url-in-css)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the inline property just make sure u enclose the URL in apostrophes like

```html
<div style="background-image: url('http://example.com/uploads/unnamed%20(41).jpg');">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
div {
  background-image: url('http://example.com/uploads/unnamed%20(41).jpg');
}
```

if it not work follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6161016/image-url-in-css)